# Designing permission system with bit flags

Tags: permissions, authorization

I am designing a permission system using bit flag in an integer for the first time and I find that I keep getting it wrong. When I finally calm down and get my head around, I realised there are 2 "directions" to approach it and I wasn't consistent throughout, causing much confusion.

Suppose I have 2 methods

```
create_contract() // sales administrators and higher
approve_contract(); // sales managers and higher
```

And I have 2 permission values

```
permission::SALES_ADMIN = 0x0001;
permission::SALES_MANAGER = 0x0002;
```

The permission checking function is

```
bool is_allowed(method_permission, user_permission)
{
    return (method_permission & user_permission) > 0
}
```

**APPROACH 1: Give each user only his role and give method every permission that can access it**

```
create_contract.permission = permission::SALES_ADMIN | permission::SALES_MANAGER;
approve_contract.permission = permission::SALES_MANAGER;
John.permission = SALES_ADMIN;
Peter.permission = SALES_MANAGER;
```

**APPROACH 2: Give user all the roles that he can act as, and give the methods the minumum role that can access it**

```
create_contract.permission = permission::SALES_ADMIN
approve_contract.permission = permission::SALES_MANAGER
John.permission = SALES_ADMIN;
Peter.permission = SALES_ADMIN | SALES_MANAGER;
```

Since this is my first time, I would like to ask if there are any functional differences between these 2 methods? Which one has more benefits and is more commonly used? Or is there an even better method?

Comment: seems like #2 is better.  reason is users may have mmultiple permissions/activities they can perform.  admins would want that fine grain control over users.

Comment: Don't mix up *permission* and *role* terms. You are actually implementing ROLEs with bit flags. That is a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is correct as it models the reality much better. Just read out loud the following sentences:

- *APPROACH 1:* Contract can be created by ADMINISTRATOR and by MANAGER.
- *APPROACH 2:* Contract can be created only by ADMINISTRATOR. All managers are automatically ADMINISTRATORS.

The second one just does not sound right.

Also you are mixing a little bit the terminology (which might be the source of confusion):

- `role` - functional position (`SALES_ADMIN` and `SALES_MANAGER`)
- `permission` - authorization to perform a specific action (`create_contract.permission` or `CREATE_CONTRACT`)

You can model *permissions* as *roles* (i.e. where the *permission type role* grants you exactly one permission), but you can not model *roles* as *permissions* (at least it sounds weird).

And final comment - usually security frameworks use bit flags to represent just `operations`. The reason is simple - there will always be a finite number of `operations`, however the number of possible `roles` or `permissions` (with growing application and new implemented functionalities) can not be limited.